# Upgrade Path for NgModuleFactoryLoader being Deprecated

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I am using this custom routing module that I got off of Medium so that I can handle routing within the web components in my parent app. I keep getting compiler warnings about NgModuleFactoryLoader and SystemJsNgModuleLoader being deprecated. Where things get interesting is when trying to move away from the deprecation to LoadChildren the Router expects loader to be an instance of NgModuleFactoryLoader. Has anyone found a way to handle this update?

```
import { MultiLocationStrategy } from './multi-location-strategy';
import { NgModule, NgModuleFactoryLoader, Compiler, Injector, Optional, ModuleWithProviders, SystemJsNgModuleLoader } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Router, UrlSerializer, ChildrenOutletContexts, ROUTES, ROUTER_CONFIGURATION,
     UrlHandlingStrategy, PreloadingStrategy, NoPreloading, provideRoutes, Routes, ExtraOptions, Route } from '@angular/router';
import { ɵROUTER_PROVIDERS as ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/router';
import { LocationStrategy, Location} from '@angular/common';
import { flatten } from '@angular/compiler';

export function setupElementsRouter(urlSerializer: UrlSerializer, contexts: ChildrenOutletContexts, location: Location,
                                    loader: NgModuleFactoryLoader, compiler: Compiler, injector: Injector,
                                    routes: Route[][], opts?: ExtraOptions,
                                    urlHandlingStrategy?: UrlHandlingStrategy): Router {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-non-null-assertion
    // the issue is here with loader 
    return new Router(null!, urlSerializer, contexts, location, injector, loader, compiler, flatten(routes));
}

@NgModule({
    exports: [RouterModule],
    providers: [
      ROUTER_PROVIDERS, {provide: Location, useClass: Location},
      {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: MultiLocationStrategy},
      { provide: NgModuleFactoryLoader, useClass: SystemJsNgModuleLoader }, {
        provide: Router,
        useFactory: setupElementsRouter,
        deps: [
          UrlSerializer, ChildrenOutletContexts, Location, NgModuleFactoryLoader, Compiler, Injector,
          ROUTES, ROUTER_CONFIGURATION, [UrlHandlingStrategy, new Optional()]
        ]
      },
      {provide: PreloadingStrategy, useExisting: NoPreloading}, provideRoutes([])
    ]
  })
  export class ElementRoutingModule {
    static withRoutes(routes: Routes, config?: ExtraOptions):
        ModuleWithProviders<ElementRoutingModule> {
      return {
        ngModule: ElementRoutingModule,
        providers: [
          provideRoutes(routes),
          {provide: ROUTER_CONFIGURATION, useValue: config ? config : {}},
        ]
      };
    }
  }
```